# What event is triggered if form is submitted by pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form>      
<div>Name:</div>
    <input name="firstname" id="typeTracking" type="text">
    <input value="Submit" id="submitTracking" type="submit">
</form>
```

And some vanilla JS code to detect when the form is submitted:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', doFancyThings);
```

But the `doFancyThings` function is only triggered if I click the submit button, not if I press the enter key on my keyboard. How can I, using only plain javascript, listen for the enter key submit event, to also trigger my `doFancyThings` function?

I've had a look in the [Event reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) and as far as I understand the submit event is only triggered when "The submit button is pressed". However, as the form is undoubtly submitted on enter key press, it ought to be firing some sort of event too, I reckon.

According to [submit - Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) the "event is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input." Which sounds a bit contrary to the previous quote, and even less understandable why my listener doesn't trigger on the enter key.

Comment: Add <form> tag.

Comment: Please show us the complete HTML. Do you have these inside a `form`?

Comment: Missed my `form` tags when I copied, updated the OP

Answer (score -1):

> not if I press the enter key

Use a `form`

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', doFancyThings);

function doFancyThings(e) {
  console.log('Enter pressed')
  e.preventDefault()

}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>Name:</div>
  <input name="firstname" id="typeTracking" type="text">
  <button value="Submit" id="submitTracking" type="submit">Click</button>

</form>
```

Comment: *is only triggered if I click the submit button* If it wasn't in a `<form>` even the click of the button wouldn't fire a `submit` event on the document. That's probably not the problem here.

Comment: as @Kaiido pointed out, I have the input fields within a form. Updated my OP.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    doFancyThings();
    e.preventDefault(); // for preventing redirect
};
form.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        doFancyThings();
        e.preventDefault(); // for preventing redirect
    }
};

function doFancyThings() {
    alert("hmmm");
};
```

```html
<form>
  <div>Name:</div>
  <input name="firstname" id="typeTracking" type="text">
  <input value="Submit" id="submitTracking" type="submit">
</form>
```